# Linear regression with multiple lag independent variables

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to undertake a linear regression on multiple lagged independent variables. I am trying to automate the part where specifying the number of lags i.e. 1,3,5,etc. would automatically update the code below and provide results with lags defined in a previous step.
My code without any 'lag' automated operation is as follows. In this instance, i have specified 2 lags :

```
base::summary(stats::lm(ABX_2000$Returns ~ stats::lag(as.ts(ABX_2000$Returns),1) + 
                              stats::lag(as.ts(ABX_2000$Returns),2)))
```

This code works!

I defined a function as follows::

```
# function to accept multiple lags
lm_lags_multiple <- function(ds,lags=2){
  base::summary(stats::lm(ds ~ paste0("stats::lag(as.ts(ds,k=(", 1:lags, ")))", collapse = " + ")))
}
# run function
lm_lags_multiple(ds=ABX_2000$Returns,lags=2)
```

On running the above function, i receive an Error message noting:

> Variable lengths are different.

I don't know how to solve this Error? Is there a lambda function equivalent in R as in Python?

Comment: A vector of lags is shorter than the original, by the amount of the lag.  You probably need to fill out the start of the lag series with zeroes, to get them the same length.

Comment: Hello @AndrewGustar. I am pretty new to R, and not sure how to solve this issue. The paste0 function [paste0("stats::lag(as.ts(ds,k=(", 1:lags, ")))", collapse = " + ")] returns [1] "stats::lag(as.ts(ds,k=(1))) + stats::lag(as.ts(ds,k=(2)))". Assigning this result to a variable results in the same error. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this code:

```
lm_lags_multiple <- function(ds,lags=2){
  lst <- list()
  for (i in 1:lags){
    lst[i] <- paste0("stats::lag(as.ts(ABX_2000$Returns),",i,")")
  }
  base::summary(stats::lm(as.formula(paste0("ds ~",paste(Reduce(c,lst), collapse = "+")))))
}
```

*Pls don't forget to let us know if it worked :)*

Comment: thank you. I got to resolve another problem, but good to know the solution